# How do I add "honoree section" to new contribution form in the backend?

Tags: contributions, honoree

My "new contribution" form in the backend does not have an "honoree" section for manual entry. I am assuming it should be there (it is enabled on our online forms). How do I enable/expose this section?

We are using 4.6.27 on D7.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution that I've come up with: first, we created a custom field set for "Honoree Section". We then create two fields in the set (or as many data fields as required for your application). In my case, 1) radio selects for "honoree type" (two types, "In Honor Of" and "In Memory Of") and 2) a text field for the name of the person memorialized with the gift.

Next we create a custom profile for contributions called "Honoree Section" and use the custom fields.

The searchable profile data can now be entered into the backend along with the soft credit. Also, the soft credit can now be entered for the *family* of the deceased, whereas the contribution can be "attributed to" the *deceased* (searchably connected to the deceased via the custom profile).

Answer (score 0):

Just below the payment details in the dark grey highlight is a section "Soft credit" that can be expended. Click on that and enter the contact info

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I knew that soft credits can be given. But, unfortunately, we'd like to be able to search by soft credit type, i.e. by whether the soft credit is a PCP, an "In Memory Of" or "In Honor Of". We are a residential substance abuse recovery program that helps people in addiction, so (sadly) we have residents that become deceased and people often want to give in memory of a deceased person. We then want to send a letter to the loved ones, caregivers, parents, etc. of the deceased acknowledging all the gifts that were given. See below. I have a solution.